# Firebase functions get key name list

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm new to the Nodejs and I'm trying to get this done for 2 days. I want to get list of key names (which are user id who liked this user) stored under a specific node. But my code doesn't proceed further then this log:
`"getting key names for user: NRtRoPEh4HUYUc0Hz6unMCsTBSn1"`

Then my code timeouts with this log: `Function execution took 60002 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'`

My code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const serviceAccount = require('./service-account.json');
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: 'MY-URL',
});

var events = require('events');

exports.getLikedUsers = functions.database.ref('/users_to_test/{pushID}').onCreate(snapshot => {
    let UID = snapshot.val();
    let likeList = new Array();
        console.log('getting key names for user: ', UID);


        return admin.database().ref(`/user_likes/${UID}/{likedUser}`)
            .once('child_added').then(snap =>
            {          
                snap.forEach((childSnap) =>{
                    likeList.push(childsnap.key);
                });

                console.log('liked users list: ' + likeList.entries());

                return;

            }).then(function (functionReturn)    
        {
        return;
        });
    });
`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is returning no results, and is waiting indefinitely until 'child_added' fires for any result to become available.  This is causing your function to time out.

Two things wrong here:

1. This ref is almost certainly not what you want: "`/user_likes/${UID}/{likedUser}`"
   You've got one variable inserted there (${UID}) and one that looks like a variable insertion, but is actually not ({likedUser}).  You are *literally* searching for a child node called "{likedUser}".  I imagine that's not what you want.
2. "child_added" queries don't really make sense in Cloud Functions.  You don't *ever* want to perform a query that waits indefinitely for a result.  You almost always want to use a "value" event to get some data a location, or nothing if the location doesn't exist, so your function can move along and do the next thing quickly.

Comment: isn't curl brackets used for letting query know there is a unknown key there? Because it only worked when I inserted {pushID} to `/users_to_test/{pushID} ` query

Comment: No, there are no wildcards in Realtime Database queries.  You're mixing that up with wildcards in the Cloud Functions path.